# SQL server Query for Bill of materials quantity

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a bill of material (bom). Lets call this BOM 301755.

BOM 301755 is made of these parts

```
    31161201 = need 1 pc of this
    29975413 = need 2 pcs of this
    299756 = need 2 pcs of this
    And 305958 = need 1 pc of this
```

This would be level zero.

Now Lets focus on one of the part. Part: 29975413.
Part 29975413 is made of:

```
PLTSSL902 = 1pc
CAPSSL902 = 1pc
PIPSSL4SCH40 = 3.96 
And LABSTR = 0.166
```

Now since we need 2 pcs of 29975413. 
how can I do the query so it will show as follows:

```
    PLTSSL902 = 1pc x 2 = 2 pc
    CAPSSL902 = 1pc x 2 = 2 pc
    PIPSSL4SCH40 = 3.96 x 2 = 7.92 
    And LABSTR = 0.166 x 2 = 0.332
```

I draw this for easier [image]to read. :)

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive Common Table Expression to walk the hierarchy of parts, passing the quantity of the parent and multiplying the children's quantities by it.

```
DECLARE @bom int = 301755

CREATE TABLE #t(
    BOM int,
    KitID varchar(20),
    SubAssy varchar(20),
    BOMLevel int,
    StdQty float
)

INSERT #t(BOM, KitID, SubAssy, BOMLevel, StdQty) VALUES 
        (301755, '301755',   '31161201', 0, 1),
        (301755, '301755',   '29975413', 0, 2),
        (301755, '301755',   '299756', 0, 2),
        (301755, '301755',   '305958', 0, 1),
        (301755, '305958',   '311620', 1, 4),
        (301755, '305958',   '311620', 1, .1),
        (301755, '299756',   'RDBSSL012', 1, .1),
        (301755, '299756',   'RDBSSL012', 1, 3.417),
        (301755, '29975413', 'PLTSSL902', 1, 1),
        (301755, '29975413', 'CAPSSL4SCH40', 1, 1),
        (301755, '29975413', 'PIPSSL4SCH40', 1, 3.96),
        (301755, '29975413', 'LABSTR', 1, .166),
        (301755, '31161201', 'PIPSSL2SCH40', 1, 4)

;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT KitID, SubAssy, StdQty FROM #t WHERE KitID = @bom
UNION ALL
    SELECT #t.KitID, #t.SubAssy, cte.StdQty * #t.StdQty FROM #t 
    INNER JOIN cte ON cte.SubAssy = #t.KitID
)


SELECT * FROM cte ORDER BY KitID, SubAssy
```

Comment: ahh thank you.. I was expecting something like this. I know I am missing something. I think this is my solution. but I will try it and let you know

Answer (score 2):

To make it a bit more general in its application I modified @dazedandconfused's answer a little bit:

```
;WITH bom as (
  SELECT pid p,cid c, qty q, 0 bomlvl FROM #t WHERE pid='301755' // start id
  UNION ALL
  SELECT pid, cid, q*qty, bomlvl+1 FROM #t INNER JOIN bom ON c=pid
)
SELECT * from bom a WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM bom WHERE p=a.c)
```

This query calculates the BOM-level for each line and will list only list only those elements of the BOM that *do not have children*, regardless of how many levels your BOM might have. A fiddle can be found [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/529064/show-total-quantities-of-all-items-used-in-a-bom).

My example will deliver the result:

```
p        c            q     bomlvl 
-------- ------------ ----- ------ 
305958   311620       4     1      
305958   311620       0.1   1      
299756   RDBSSL012    0.2   1      
299756   RDBSSL012    6.834 1      
29975413 PLTSSL902    2     1      
29975413 CAPSSL4SCH40 2     1      
29975413 PIPSSL4SCH40 7.92  1      
29975413 LABSTR       0.332 1      
31161201 PIPSSL2SCH40 4     1
```

You could go one step further and group the results by their `c`-id to get their **total amounts** used in a particular BOM. A table valued function would be the best way of writing this, where you pass the initial Id as a parameter. I cannot demonstrate this in my data.stackexchange-fiddle since functions cannot reference temporary tables, but the function definition should look more or less like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION bomqty ( @pid varchar(20) ) RETURNS TABLE AS BEGIN
;WITH bom as (
  SELECT pid p,cid c, qty q, 0 bomlvl FROM tbl WHERE pid=@pid
  UNION ALL
  SELECT pid, cid, q*qty, bomlvl+1 FROM tbl INNER JOIN bom ON c=pid
)
RETURN SELECT c item,sum(q) totalqty FROM bom a 
       WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM bom WHERE p=a.c)
       GROUP BY c
END;
```

The function can then be used like any other table like this:

```
SELECT * FROM bomqty('301755')
```

This will get you

```
item         totalqty 
------------ -------- 
311620       4.1      
CAPSSL4SCH40 2        
LABSTR       0.332    
PIPSSL2SCH40 4        
PIPSSL4SCH40 7.92     
PLTSSL902    2        
RDBSSL012    7.034
```

Comment: interesting tips on using "not exists".  I will give it a try. thank you

Answer (score 1):

something like this should work:

```
CREATE TABLE #TableBom
(
 Bom INT
,KitId INT
,SubAssy VARCHAR(20)
,BomLevel INT
,StdQty DECIMAL(10 ,3)
);

INSERT INTO #TableBom
SELECT 301755, 301755, '29975413', 0, 2
UNION ALL
SELECT 301755, 29975413, 'PLTSSL902', 1, 1
UNION ALL
SELECT 301755, 29975413, 'CAPSSL902', 1, 1
UNION ALL
SELECT 301755, 29975413, 'PIPSSL4SCH40',1,3.96
UNION ALL
SELECT 301755, 29975413, 'LABSTR', 1, 0.166
UNION ALL
SELECT 301755, 299756, 'RDBSSL012', 1, 3.147

SELECT  b.Bom
   ,b2.SubAssy
   ,CONCAT(b2.SubAssy, ' = ' ,CAST(b2.StdQty AS DECIMAL(10,3)) ,' pc x ' ,CAST(b.StdQty AS DECIMAL(10,3)) ,' = ' ,CAST((b2.StdQty * b.StdQty) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) ,' pc') AS Calc
FROM    #TableBom AS b
    INNER JOIN #TableBom AS b2 ON b.SubAssy = CAST(b2.KitId AS VARCHAR(20));
```

`Bom    SubAssy         Calc
301755  PLTSSL902       PLTSSL902 = 1.000 pc x 2.000 = 2.00 pc
301755  CAPSSL902       CAPSSL902 = 1.000 pc x 2.000 = 2.00 pc
301755  PIPSSL4SCH40    PIPSSL4SCH40 = 3.960 pc x 2.000 = 7.92 pc
301755  LABSTR          LABSTR = 0.166 pc x 2.000 = 0.33 pc`

EDIT:
if you only want to include the 29975413 you can include a `WHERE b.SubAssy = '29975413'`

Comment: hey thanks for the answer. Sorry I didn't meant to have the formatting like that . I just need an idea how to do the calculation.. But I will give this a try.

Comment: Ahh ok. would just need to take out everything from the concat, and keep `(b2.StdQty * b.StdQty)`