# Recursive joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursive-query

I have two tables defined below (note that the **Regions** table is recursive and that the recursion can potentially have many levels).

**Regions**

| Id | ParentId | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | EU |
| 2 | 1 | Germany |
| 3 | 1 | France |

**Cities**

| Id | Name | RegionId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Berlin | 2 |
| 2 | Hamburg | 2 |
| 3 | Paris | 3 |
| 4 | Nice | 3 |

I want to see how many cities there are in a particular region. Desired output below:

| Region | CityCount |
| --- | --- |
| EU | 4 |
| Germany | 2 |
| France | 2 |

This query gives me the count of cities in every child region, but how do I join in the recursive table to also get the parent (in this case `EU`) region?

```
select R.Name, count(C.Id)
from Regions R
join Cities C on C.RegionId = R.Id
group by R.Name
having count(C.Id) > 1
```

I've tried to simplify a real-world problem I'm facing, this is obviously the simplification.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks, added.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL server Query for Bill of materials quantity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39153256/sql-server-query-for-bill-of-materials-quantity)

Comment: @Serg tbh not sure how to adapt this to my case, will try to figure out

Comment: Side note: did you really want `having count(C.Id) > 1` or rather `>= 1`? If the latter, you can just omit it, since you're doing an `inner join` anyway...

Comment: @buddemat I did want it in the real case and it came in here by accident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE to flatten your `regions` tree:

```
with flatregions as
(
  select t.ID, t.ParentID, t.Name, 1 as lvl
  from regions t

  union all

  select t.ID, tt.ParentID, tt.Name, t.lvl+1
  from flatregions t
  inner join regions tt on tt.ID = t.ParentID
)
select * FROM flatregions;
```

| ID | ParentID | Name | lvl |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | EU | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | Germany | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | France | 1 |
| 3 |  | EU | 2 |
| 2 |  | EU | 2 |

Then use that CTE in the `JOIN` of your `cities` table:

```
with flatregions as
(
  select t.ID, t.ParentID, t.Name, 1 as lvl
  from regions t

  union all

  select t.ID, tt.ParentID, tt.Name, t.lvl+1
  from flatregions t
  inner join regions tt on tt.ID = t.ParentID
)
select R.Name, count(C.Id) as CityCount
from flatregions R
join Cities C on C.RegionId = R.Id
group by R.Name
having count(C.Id) > 1
```

| Region | CityCount |
| --- | --- |
| EU | 4 |
| Germany | 2 |
| France | 2 |

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c76e4eef8b42190b2b35dd80bea2129e).

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be what you're after. You can use an rCTE to move through the hierachy to the root, but each iteration retains certain information; in this case the name of the original node. Then you can still `JOIN` on the `RegionID`:

```sql
WITH rCTE AS(
    SELECT R.ID,
           R.ParentID,
           R.[Name]
    FROM dbo.Regions R
    UNION ALL
    SELECT R.ID,
           R.ParentID,
           C.[Name]
    FROM dbo.Regions R
         JOIN rCTE C ON R.ParentID = C.ID)
SELECT r.[Name],
       COUNT(*) AS CityCount
FROM rCTE r
     JOIN dbo.Cities C ON r.ID = C.RegionID
GROUP BY r.[Name];
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=298cd97d014625428471a6121a4915ce)

Comment: Thanks! Marking the other answer as accepted as (s)he answered first, but upvoting. :)